# Apply distinct on the basis of item2 of List of integer tuples in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, tuples

I have a List of integer tuple

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> list =  new  List<Tuple<int, int>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,12));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,2));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,18));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,12));
```

I want to remove the redundant value of item2 which is 12 in this case

The updated list should also be List>.      (same type) but with distinct values.The new tuple of type  List>  should contain only following:

```
 list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,2));
 list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,18));
 list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1,12));
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you only care about the second tuple value?  Meaning, thats the only one you need to distinct on?  Or only duplicate matches of item1 and item2?

Comment: so thats the problem i need both values i.e i want the tuple of the same type with both the values

Comment: that comment makes no sense.  What happens if you have a Tuple with (2,12), should that be part of your output since the first value is unique or should it be excluded because the second value is a duplicate?

Comment: i want to retain both the values item1 and item2 in the new tuple but i have to apply distinct on the basis of item2. Acc. to the above example one 2,12 will be removed because item2 12 is  2 times. So my new tue will contain 3 values instead of 4

Comment: Then the second part of my answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you want only the unique pairs of numbers this can easily be done by using `Distinct()`:

```
list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

If you only care about removing duplicates of *only* Item2, then use `GroupBy()` and `Select()` the `First()` of each group:

```
list = list.GroupBy(x => x.Item2).Select(x => x.First());
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FJi5RN) that demonstrates both methods

**EDIT**

From your latest comment, it sounds like you want to use the second method I have proposed (GroupBy Item2 and Select the First of each Group).