# Distinct or GroupBy on a list which made of tuple<string,string,string>

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have a list of tuple : `List<Tuple<string,string,string>>`

When I run my program, my List have this :

```
List[0] : 'Cars','Bird','1.0';
List[1] : 'Plane','Flower','2.0';
List[2] : 'Cars','Bird','1.0';
List[3] : 'Plane','Flower','2.0';
```

I want to make a group by in linq on my List to have only two lines  :

```
List[0] : 'Cars','Bird','1.0';
List[1] : 'Plane','Flower','2.0';
```

They are the same, so I don't need to repeat it.

I already tried a lot of things. I Know how to make a groupby on a column.

But on a Tuple of 3 strings, I don't know.

During my tests, I have 4 lines. I only want Two lines as explained.

Comment: `List<Tuple<string, string, string>> result = source.Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: I don't understand the question. What did you tried? https://dotnetfiddle.net/BbN7Pj. Both Distinct and GroupBy works. What was you error on your try? Mind sharing a simple [mcve] simple.

Comment: As We are kind of colleague (I worked in as a teach for a "centre de formation professionnel"), here is by best advice. 1/; Read [Ask] and [mcve], it's usefull tool that I still use in every day professional life. You can even translate them for the student. Being clear and precise and providing a demo pieces of code instead of a whole solution will be an improvement for them.  2/; Swap your name to an Alias- Students can act weirdly when they find us.

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693620/apply-distinct-on-the-basis-of-item2-of-list-of-integer-tuples-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

If you really have `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>`, you could do just `myList.Distinct()`.

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>> {
 Tuple.Create("a", "b", "1"),
 Tuple.Create("aa", "bb", "1"),
 Tuple.Create("a", "b", "1"), 
 Tuple.Create("aa", "bb", "1")};

myList.Distinct().Dump();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a `GroupBy` function, but a [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8) function.

Tuples support equality checks, therefore in order to remove all the duplicates you can just write:

```cs
var listWithoutDuplicates = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

If it weren't tuples or another type that implements the [IEquatable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8) generic interface, you would want to use a `DistinctBy` function, that since it doesn't have a native .NET implementation, you can read more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property).

Comment: `var myList = myList.Distinct().ToList();` if we want to get `List<>` as a result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by all columns then you can use just Distinct extension method.

```
list.Distinct();
```

If you want to group by single column:

```
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
    list.Add(Tuple.Create("Cars", "Bird", "1.0"));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create("Plane", "Flower", "1.0"));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create("Cars", "Bird", "2.0"));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create("Plane", "Flower", "2.0"));

    foreach (var group in list.GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key);

        foreach (var tuple in group)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  " + tuple);
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
Cars
  (Cars, Bird, 1.0)
  (Cars, Bird, 2.0)
Plane
  (Plane, Flower, 1.0)
  (Plane, Flower, 2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by Item1,Item2 & Item3

```
var myList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>> {
 Tuple.Create("a", "b", "1"),
 Tuple.Create("aa", "bb", "1"),
 Tuple.Create("a", "b", "1"), 
 Tuple.Create("aa", "bb", "1")};

var result = myList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item1, x.Item2,x.Item3})
```